# listplot and (0,0)

Tags: pstricks, animate, pst-plot, multido

Look at the following minimal working example.

I cannot understand, why the first line of listplot is plotted from (0,0) to the first data of the input file.

I am compiling with

```
% converting with batchfile
%latex --enable-write18 --src -interaction=nonstopmode --save-size=80000 %A%.tex
%dvips -P pdf -D1200 %A%.dvi
%ps2pdf %A%.ps

\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% \IfFileExists{testdaten.dat}{}{
\begin{filecontents}{testdaten.dat}
0.0,4.0
0.1,3.27704
0.2,2.7192
0.3,2.30629
0.4,2.0192
0.5,1.83984
0.6,1.7512
0.7,1.73729
0.8,1.7832
0.9,1.87504
1.0,2.0
1.1,2.14629
1.2,2.3032
1.3,2.46104
1.4,2.6112
1.5,2.74609
1.6,2.8592
1.7,2.94504
1.8,2.9992
1.9,3.01829
2.0,3.0
2.1,2.94304
2.2,2.8472
2.3,2.71329
2.4,2.5432
2.5,2.33984
2.6,2.10720
2.7,1.85029
2.8,1.5752
2.9,1.28904
3.0,1.0
3.1,0.71729
3.2,0.45120
3.3,0.21304
3.4,0.01519
3.5,-0.1289
3.6,-0.2047
3.7,-0.1969
3.8,-0.0887
3.9,0.13729
4.0,0.50000}
\end{filecontents}
% }



\readdata{\data}{testdaten.dat} % Daten auslesen

\begin{document}
% \multido{\iC=1+1}{40}
\multido{\iC=40+1}{1}
    {
    \begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-0.5) (4 ,4)
    \psaxes[axesstyle=frame,origin={0,0},tickstyle=bottom, xyDecimals=0,labels=y]{->}(0,0)(0,0) (4 ,4)

            \listplot[nStart=1,nEnd=\iC\space,plotstyle=line, dotstyle=x, linewidth=1.93pt, linecolor=blue]{\data}  % Punkte Blau

    \end{pspicture}
    }
\end{document}
```

Look at the multido command. This one prints only one picture and this picture should be the same as the last one of the other multido command. but the first frame of

```
 \multido{\iC=1+1}{40}
```

prints a line from (0,0) to (0.0,4.0) which seems to be not correct or I am not able to understand listplot.

Goal: The first picture on one page should be the last multido picture, then all pictures should occure except the last one.

The order of 40 picture should be
40,1,2,3,4,...,39

In this case you can make animated pictures and the would be capable with any pdf reader. No information is lost, the animation would only start in acrobat....

best regrads

EDIT1:
Additional Infos:

```
 *File List*
standalone.cls    2012/09/15 v1.1b Class to compile TeX sub-files standalone
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 xkeyval.sty    2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
standalone.cfg    2012/09/15 v1.1b Default configuration file for 'standalone' 
class
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
pstricks.sty    2013/12/12 v0.60 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
pstricks.tex    2014/03/12 v2.53 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
  pst-fp.tex    2014/03/12 v2.53 `PST-fp' (hv)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
   dvips.def    1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
pst-plot.sty    2011/04/13 package wrapper for pst-plot.tex (hv)
pst-xkey.sty    2005/11/25 v1.6 package wrapper for pst-xkey.tex (HA)
 multido.sty    2004/05/17 package wrapper for PSTricks `multido.tex', (HV/RN)
 multido.tex    2010/05/14 v1.42 `multido' (tvz,hv)
pst-plot.tex    2014/03/12 1.61 `pst-plot' (tvz,hv)
filecontents.sty    2011/10/08 v1.3 Create an external file from within a LaTeX
```

Second Multido Command with only one picture
[image: Second multido]

First Multido Command with 40 pictures, the first one can be seen here....
[image: First multido]

Peter

Comment: This doesn't happen on my computer.

Comment: @Bernard I have tried again. It still occurs. What information should I share to find any trace of the reason?

Comment: Maybe the .log file. Anyway, delete blank lines in the pspicture environments: pstricks doesn't like that. Which versions of pstricks and pst-plot do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it makes no sense to use

```
\multido{\iC=1+1}{40}{%
```

with `plotstyle=line` because you have only one point for `\iC=1`; the reason why `(0,0)` is used for the second one.

Use instead `plotstyle=dots` or

```
\multido{\iC=2+1}{40}{%
```

if you want lines. Starting the animation with a dot at `0,4` is possible with  copying this pair of coordinates so that it appears twice.

The output with `showpoints` and `\iC=2+1` and two starting points:

[image]

Comment: As I can see your answer and your explanation, it was clear that my code could not work as expected. The only bug that I found that way is a lack of thinking about the goal of each command. What a pitty that I could not determin this locical answer by myself.

Thanks to Herbert.